# Prevent dragging of a child element

Tags: angular, angular-cdk-drag-drop

I have a container with 4 child elements.

[image]

I want to prevent dragging if i click on any of the Node element. But i want to drag the chart-container if i drag from anywhere else.

```
<div class="chart-container" #wrapper cdkDrag>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let node of nodes; let i = index">
      <div
        class="box"
        [id]="node.id"
        [ngClass]="{ target: node.type === 'target' }"
        [style.top.px]="node?.uiPosition?.top || 20"
        [style.left.px]="node?.uiPosition?.left || 20"
      >
        <div class="node">
          {{ 'Node' + (i + 1) }}
        </div>
      </div>
    </ng-container>
   <div class="example-handle" cdkDragHandle></div>
</div>
```

```
.example-handle {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: transparent;
  z-index: 5;
}
```

I added a div with lower z-index and added cdkDragHandle to it and now i'm able to drag the container. But is there a better way to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

`If you want to disable dragging for a particular drag item, you can do so by setting the cdkDragDisabled input on a cdkDrag item. Furthermore, you can disable an entire list using the cdkDropListDisabled input on a cdkDropList or a particular handle via cdkDragHandleDisabled on cdkDragHandle.`

This is what the doc says. Did you try it ?

Comment: I don't want to disabled a particular dragItem. The entire container is draggable. I want to prevent it's dragging if i click and drag from the node elements

Comment: The author explained that he wants to block part of the block. And not one element from a list element, ng-for etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the status for `cdkDragDisabled` of the parent element when the cursor enters an area that should not drag the block.
To do this, create an `isBlockDraggable = true` property and change its state from true to false using the `mouseover` and `mouseout` events.

```
<div class="chart-container" cdkDrag [cdkDragDisabled]="isBlockDraggable">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let node of nodes">
      <div (mouseout)="isBlockDraggable=false"
           (mouseover)="isBlockDraggable=true">
        <div class="node">
          {{ node.value }}
        </div>
      </div>
    </ng-container>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue so i had to manually stop the event propagation to the parent element. I disabled it on
**drag**, **dragstart** and **dragend**
events but parent element was still dragged using the child.
In the end i stopped the **mousedown** event.

html:

```
<app-slider (mousedown)="disableDragging($event)"></app-slider>
```

component:

```
disableDragging(event) {
 event.preventDefault();
 event.stopPropagation();
}
```